# Cursor For loop using subquery and Associative array?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, cursor, associative-array

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE report_credit
(p_email customers.cust_last_name%TYPE,
p_credit_limit customers.credit_limit%TYPE)
IS
  TYPE typ_name IS TABLE OF customers%ROWTYPE
    INDEX BY customers.cust_email%TYPE;
  v_by_cust_email typ_name;
  i VARCHAR2(30);
  PROCEDURE load_arrays IS
  BEGIN
    FOR rec IN (SELECT * FROM customers
                WHERE cust_email IS NOT NULL) LOOP
      v_by_cust_email (rec.cust_email) := rec;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

v_by_cust_email (rec.cust_email) := rec;

i am not getting the meaning of that line, what kind of assignment is it?

Comment: It means: assign the value (contents) of variable `rec` to a row in array `v_by_cust_email` (which is and must be of same structure).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is creating an associative array - *a key, value pair* - in memory indexed or keyed by the customers email address. The array's *value* is a record of the same structure as a row in the customers table e.g.

```
v_cust_by_email('joe.bloggs@anisp.com') = customer('Joe', 'Bloggs', 100.00)
v_cust_by_email('john.doe@anotherisp.com') = customer('John', 'Doe', 500.00)
v_cust_by_email('jane.doe@anotherisp.com') = customer('Jane', 'Doe', 250.00)
```

This would allow you then to lookup values in this array directly by the email address in later processing, without either querying the database table or looping through the associative array and comparing a supplied email address with those in the array.